# landscape to portrait view is not working

Tags: android, android-orientation

I want to change my `view` as per orientation.
For that, I have created the `layout-land` & `layout-port` folder in resources.
The orientation portrait to landscape of view is working but landscape to portrait view is not working. Why this is happening?

my .manifest file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="in.wptrafficanalyzer.landportdemo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
  </manifest>
```

port/main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="this is my portrait view" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

    />

 </LinearLayout>
```

land/main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="this is my Landscape view" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

    />

   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your androidmanifest.xml code in question

Comment: and related code for layouts and the view.

Comment: have you created layout xml files into those folders..?

Comment: yes I have created for both view landscape and portrait

Comment: are those files having same name..?

Comment: @andr:i have posted my code please check it.

Answer (score 3):

Rename the folder name layout-port to layout only and in manifest.xml file add an attribute in activity tag

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```